# Is $U$ diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Assume that $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space, and $T, U \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ are such that $TU = UT$, and the characteristic polynomial of $T$ has $n$ distinct roots.
> Is $U$ diagonalizable?
> Justify your answer.
> ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8JUM.png))

Well clearly $T$ and $U$ are commutative and since T has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, it has $n$ distinct linearly independent eigenvectors. This means that $U$ is diagonalizable. Am I on the right track? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have the right idea, but I'd like to elaborate a bit:

Suppose $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of T with corresponding eigenvector $v_i$. Then $TUv_i=UTv_i=\lambda_iUv_i$.This means $Uv_i$ is an eigenvector of T which corresponds to the same eigenvalue as $v_i$. Since the eigenvectors of T are linearly independent, this implies $Uv_i$ is a scalar multiple of $v_i$, say $Uv_i=\mu_iv_i$. In other words, T and U have the same eigenvectors, and thus U is diagonalizable.